# Inserting an inverted exclamation mark into a sqlite table

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

For the life of me I can't figure this out, i've been browsing the web and can't find an answer but also been coding all day so my brain is fried. Currently i'm prepending the inverted exclamation mark to a string like this

```
NSString *randomString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@random!", @"\u00A1"];
```

which logs what I want which is

```
@"¡random!"
```

So then I insert it into my sqlite database and use the string value given above like so

```
if(!(self.dbOpen))
{
    [self openDatabaseWithSQLName:@"SMCachedDB.db"];
}

sqlInsertStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@(%@) VALUES(%@)", useTable, myColumns, myValues];
char *error;

// Execute statement
if(sqlite3_exec(cachedDatabase, [sqlInsertStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    hasBeenAdded = YES;
    NSLog(@"Entry added into '%@' table", useTable);
} else {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(cachedDatabase));
    NSLog(@"ERROR inserting '%@'", myValues);
    hasBeenAdded = NO;
}
```

the string is within the "myValues" string so everything is getting stored correctly but when I select back the values I get the unicode characters before my string like so

```
"\U00a1random!";
```

I'm sure I'm missing something dumb. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A string appended with commas and values that are going to be inserted into the table.

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to store "\U00a1random!" with a capital U?

Comment: Yea positive, I just check my code to ensure it.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT hex(MyValue) FROM MyTable` for this record?

Comment: How are you displaying the value?  NSLog will display non-ASCII characters in escaped notation.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. It stores the string with the actual unicode characters prepended to it so when I was logging the data stored in the database it returned

```
"\u00A1random!"
```

I thought the it would've stored the variable as `"¡"` and not the actual unicode. So when I selected the value from the database and logged it it returned the value that was necessary which was

```
"¡random!"
```

After coming back to it I seemed to figure it out within 5 minutes after spending all that time last night on it, sorry guys.

Comment: The "compiler" didn't figure anything out -- it can only interpret string literals at the point they are coded.  But note that if you NSLog a non-ASCII character it's apt to be displayed in Unicode escape notation.